# npm run watch build successfully and laravel mix but on browser can't reached ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: laravel, notifications

When i am try to run on my laravel real time application with pusher:

```
npm run watch
```

the Compiled successfully and laravel mix build successfully but when i open Browser and try to reach url

```
http://localhost:8000
or 
http://localhost:8001
or
http://localhost:8079
or
http://localhost:8080
```

all this port same error on browser i found `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on the Browser however i am run server and mysql correct

However i run php artisan serve the app work fine

this my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

window._ = require('lodash');

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');


// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('order', require('./components/orderNotification.vue'));
const app = new vue({

    el: '#app',

    data: {
        orders: '',
    },

    created() {
        if (window.Laravel.userId) {
            axios.post('/notification/order/notification').then(response => {
                this.orders = response.data;
                console.log(response.data)
            });

            Echo.private('App.user.' + window.Laravel.userId).notification((response) => {

                data = { "data": response };
                this.orders.push(data);
                console.log(response.data)

            });
        }
    }
});
```

and this bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');


/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}



window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';


let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}


import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true
});
```

Comment: `npm run watch` is used for compiling assets using laravel mix. The `php artisan serve` actually starts the built in web server. The `npm run watch` does nothing else than compiling your assets into a single file, for as far as i'm aware. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#running-mix